# How can I get element from List<File>?

Tags: java

In Java, I have a following declaration:

```
public List<File> getAllFiles(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(createdFiles);
    }
```

I want to access the object (file) that is first on that list. How can I best do it?

Comment: Tried `getAllFiles().get(0)`??

Comment: Want the first element in list, or read the file from harddisk?

Answer (score 4):

```
getAllFiles().iterator().next();
```

or

```
getAllFiles().get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

`File file = getAllFiles().get(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check whether the list is empty.

```
 List<File> allFiles = getAllFiles();

 if (allFiles.size() == 0) {
   // handle this situation as you like.
 } else {
    File file = allFiles.get(0);
    // ...
 }
```

Since you want the first element I think you should avoid to the iterator approach as, depending on the implementation, you would create a object unnecessary: the iterator.

Comment: Don't forget to check for `null`.

Comment: @Andy. The question code of getAllFiles() is guaranteed not to return a null; if the element themselves can be a null, that is another story. The question asks about the first element of the list and not the first non-null element so the answer I propose does the job.